# Purpose of BAV99

Tags: diodes

I'm trying to understand [ChipWhisperer](https://github.com/newaetech/chipwhisperer/tree/master/hardware/capture/chipwhisperer-lite/pcb/eagle) schematics.
Can anyone help me understand the purpose of BAV99(D1) in this case

[image: https://github.com/newaetech/chipwhisperer/tree/master/hardware/capture/chipwhisperer-lite/pcb/eagle]

I thought this kind of diodes act as clamping diodes to protect the input against too high or too low voltages. But this wiring doesn't make any sense for me.

Comment: Show more of the schematic for better context.  These are obviously two diodes in series, but without more context we can't see what their purpose is.

Comment: Looks like its limiting that signal to 1.4Vish to me...

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not really familiar with electronic-engineering world, but the link leads to sch file, which I thought can be recognised as eagle schematics extension. What kind of other schematics can help? This circuit is part of ADC + Preamplifier if it helps.

Comment: Kirill, we don't all have Eagle. You took a screen shot of part of a circuit. Zoom out and take another one with enough surrounding detail that we can figure out what's going on. What is the circuit for? VGA? Input / output?

Comment: It's just an ADC circuit used for side-channel attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [AD8331 datasheet](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8331_8332_8334.pdf), the useful range of voltages applied to the GAIN pin to adjust the gain is 0 to 1.0 V. And the absolute maximum voltage to be applied to the GAIN pin is 2.5 V.

With the series resistors R52 and R53, these diodes clamp the input voltage at the GAIN pin to no more than about 1.4 V. If whatever drives the VGA_GAIN input isn't able to produce a negative voltage, this keeps the GAIN pin in its safe operating range.

The unconnected "T" connection between the diodes is just the third pin of a dual diode package, which isn't being used in this circuit.

Answer (score 1):

In this context the diodes are providing a 1.4V clamp.
Probably for this reason given in the datasheet of the AD8331 which talks about the RCLMP pin:

> Output clamping can be used for ADC input overload protection, if
>   needed, or postamp overload protection when operating from a lower
>   common-mode level, such as 1.5 V. The user should be aware that
>   distortion products increase as output levels approach the clamping
>   levels, and the user should adjust the clamp resistor accordingly.

Comment: Yes, I saw this kind of wiring, but in my case "signal" pin is not connected at all. And I'm trying to understand why.

Comment: @lapto2d: They're not connected like that though. They're both in series to ground with a tee from the centre connection going nowhere. There's nothing in the [Analog Devices datasheet](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8331_8332_8334.pdf) that would give a clue.

Comment: Yeah, I was providing the 'normal' way you hook them up to compare the two

Comment: @Transistor, in the datasheet, the useful range for adjusting gain is 0 to 1 V, and the abs max voltage on the GAIN pin is 2.5 V. So clamping the voltage somewhere between 1 and 2.5 V makes sense.

Comment: I just love hitting a moving target answer

Comment: The paragraph you quote from the datasheet is about clamping the output of the VGA, not the control input; although similar logic may apply.

Comment: Its talking about the RCLAMP pin